# Which is the next shape in the pattern?

Tags: pattern

I don't know whether this puzzle is easy or hard, and whether it is nice or lame, but decided to post it anyway. It is possible later to add extra images or to edit the current ones, depending on your feedback.

**Which of the yellow tiles complements the sequence formed by the grey tiles?**
[image]

HINT:

> This puzzle is part of this week's fortnight challenge.

Comment: I don't quite understand, or we looking for a yellow tile which continues the sequence or are we rearranging the yellow tiles to match the grey ones?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, you need to pick one of the yellow tiles which would continue the sequence formed by the grey tiles.

Comment: sure, ill join now

Comment: Just a thought: might this relate to particle sizes? Water (molecule) hydrogen atom, A for atom? + proton, M muon? Things like this

Comment: @AvikMohan, it is not related to particles, but I think your type of thinking is going in the right direction.

Comment: Is "complements the sequence" supposed to be "**completes** the sequence"?

Comment: @Kat Not really "completes", more like is following it.

Comment: Maybe edit to say "which of the yellow tile comes next in the sequence..." then? I had no idea what you were asking from the current wording.

Comment: @Kat, yes, I think "comes next" would also work, but I feel "complements" is more accurate, since generally the continuation is not unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is

> the third one : the world (or world wide web)

Because :

> We have here (left to right) : fire, wheel, writing, calculus, magnetism and electricity which are human discovers along time

Comment: That's the precise logic, there is just a more appropriate symbol than the clock there.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan, so the fourth, because it is a toaster : )

Comment: Haha, it was supposed to be Roman numerals. I will accept your answer, just change it to the WWW symbol (third one).

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan, thanks ! this is my first accepted here !! YaY !

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be:

> The smiley emoticon

As:

> The water drop is a (realistic/relatable) image. The circle-dot is a scientific picture (hydrogen). 'A' is a letter. The '+' is a mathematical letter. The compass is a direction in radial/degree units. The 'M' is a graph. It's all ways of communicating information. The emoticon could either be visual emotion or emotes on a phone. Both are ways of communicating.

To note,

> The 'world' picture I thought could refer to the web/internet, so that's bugging me. But then again you use the web to send the information, but characters etc. to convey the information. Also, I thought time, but time is information that we convey, not the numbers we use *to* convey the information.

Comment: You kinda got the logic, but still not completely there. I updated the image a little bit, may want to take another look:)